# Can't Find Symbol in my method instance?

Tags: java

This a very quick and i feel obvious mistake but i keep getting the CANNOT FIND SYMBOL

```
symbol : method print(int,int)
```

this would lead me to believe that i'm not giving the method the right data type parameters, however..

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestSrv srvObj = new TestSrv();

        srvObj.print(0, 0);
        srvObj.print(1, 1);
        srvObj.print(2, 10);
    }
}
```

and this method, what it's meant to do aside, i keep getting errors from the above code for all 3 calls to the print method? I am passing it integers on all 3 occasions?

```
 public class TestSrv
    {
        public void print(int num, int count)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= count; ++i)
                {
                    System.out.print(num + ". " + "*");
                }
            }       
    }
```

Comment: check this http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html#CANNOTFINDSYMBOL

Comment: It should compile happily. If you are using eclipse ide try cleaning the project, some times ide's gives the errors after having correct code.

Comment: i am not :/ only using jEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should compile.   Make sure that you declare both classes in the same package or that you import TestSrv in Test.java.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly didn't compile `TestSrv` after making changes. Using an IDE such as Eclipse or IDEA will take care of much of that detail for you.

Comment: ah, i am only using jEdit

Answer (score 0):

while renaming my method and class and such so that it wasn't what i originally named it(as to not confuse anyone) i actually fixed the problem that i had.. that is why this compiled for everyone xD i feel stupid! thanks again